# Maintaining State Locally Within a Closure in Swift

Tags: swift, closures

Is there any way to have a variable declared within a closure and have it maintain its state between enumerated calls.  Specifically, I would like to write a .filter closure on an array that returns a version of the array without duplicates.  Something like this.

```
let withDupes = ["C", "D", "A", "J", "J", "D", "M", "Z", "A"]  

let noDupes = withDupes.filter {  
    static var seenLetters: [Character] = [ ]  //would like to use static like in C  
    if !contains(seenLetters, $0) {  
        seenLetters.append($0)  
                return true  
            }  
            else {  
                return false  
            }  
    }
```

// noDupes ideally would now be ["C", "D", "A", "J", "M", "Z"]

Swift reports an error when I try to use static this way, and the .filter works fine if I declare seenLetters globally.  Is there a language feature I am missing or misusing?

Answer (score 1):

As you've found, Swift doesn't let you define `static` variables directly in functions or closures. However, there's another way to accomplish what you're trying to do. If you move your de-duplication code in to its own function, you can create a `seenLetters` `Array` scoped to that function and use that within your `filter` call.  Like so:

```
let withDupes = ["C", "D", "A", "J", "J", "D", "M", "Z", "A"]

func deduplicate(arr: [String]) -> [String] {
    var seenLetters = [String]()
    return arr.filter {
        if !contains(seenLetters, $0) {
            seenLetters.append($0)
            return true
        }
        else {
            return false
        }
    }
}

let noDupes = deduplicate(withDupes)
```

Note that, since you can embed functions in other functions, this works just fine:

```
func someFunction() {
    let withDupes = ["C", "D", "A", "J", "J", "D", "M", "Z", "A"]

    func deduplicate(arr: [String]) -> [String] {
        /* ... */
    }

    let noDupes = deduplicate(withDupes)
}
```

If you want to don't want to create a separate function to do this for some reason, you can actually do this purely with closures as well. The trick is to wrap your closure in another closure which defines a local `seenLetters` variable and returns your original closure. That way, `seenLetters` is scoped to the outer closure and your inner closure can use it as you intend.

```
let noDupes = withDupes.filter({
    var seenLetters = [String]()
    return {
        if !contains(seenLetters, $0) {
            seenLetters.append($0)
            return true
        }
        else {
            return false
        }
    }
}()) // Immediately calling the outer closure so that the inner one is returned to filter
```

A few things to note... One, you need to pass the return value of the outer closure to the `filter` function, which you do by simply calling it immediately. Two, you can't use this as a trailing closure, so you have to wrap it in `()`s in your `filter` call. Three, this is basically the same thing as using an embedded function, it's just in a more compact form.